# R não cria gráfico corretamente

Tags: r

Estou utilizando R para gerar gráficos de uma table, com dois campos (nome da empresa e quantidade de vendas), ao utilizar barplot, ele não está colocando os valores certos nos campos.

Por exemplo, se as vendas foram 500.000 ele vai fazer no gráfico o maior valor 500, ou seja ele está deixando de lado os milhares.

Como poderia solucionar esse problema? E barplot é a melhor alternativa para gerar gráficos de registros semelhantes a esse:

- Nome/Vendas

  - 1     AMAZON/25.268
  - 2      APPLE/743.928
  - 3      CISCO/792.597
  - 4     GOOGLE/780.093
  - 5 HP COMPANY/108.600
  - 6        IBM/144.234
  - 7      INTEL/66.400
  - 8  MICROSOFT/589.300
  - 9    NETFLIX/1.614

**Edit:** Saída do comando dput(tabela)

```
structure(list(Nome = structure(1:9, .Label = c("AMAZON", "APPLE","CISCO", "GOOGLE", "HP COMPANY", "IBM", "INTEL", "MICROSOFT","NETFLIX"), class = "factor"), Vendas = c(25.268, 743.928, 792.597,780.093, 108.6, 144.234, 66.4, 589.3, 1.614)), .Names = c("Nome", "Vendas"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Troquei os pontos por "," e ele passou a dar o seguinte erro:

```
Error in barplot.default(empresas$Vendas, names.arg = empresas$Nome, main = "Venda por empresa de TI",  :   'height' deve ser um vetor ou uma matriz
```

Comment: provavelmente o problema está na leitura dos seus dados... edite a sua pergunta colocando o resultado de `dput(tabela)`, para ficar mais fácil de responder!

Comment: O problema está nos seus números, o separador de ponto é decimal no R.

Comment: Quando troquei o ponto por virgula, deu esse erro:
Error in barplot.default(empresas$Vendas, names.arg = empresas$Nome, main = "Venda por empresa de TI",  :   'height' deve ser um vetor ou uma matriz

Comment: @Rafael você não pode colocar vírgula. Ou vai truncar o número ou vai transformar o número em texto.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli como eu posso fazer os números aparecerem corretos no gráfico, sem que eles fiquem como os que você gerou?

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta, rafael.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli Por exemplo, eu gostaria que aparece-se 600.000 ao invés de 6e+05.

Answer (score 5):

O seu problema está na leitura dos dados. Não salve o seu csv com ponto como separador de milhares, pois o ponto é separador de decimal no R. Por exemplo, retirando os pontos na mão nos seus dados o `barplot` funciona normalmente.

```
empresas <- structure(list(Nome = structure(1:9, 
                                            .Label = c("AMAZON", "APPLE","CISCO", "GOOGLE", "HP COMPANY", "IBM", "INTEL", "MICROSOFT","NETFLIX"), 
                                            class = "factor"), 
                           Vendas = c(25268, 743928, 792597,780093, 1086, 144234, 664, 5893, 1614)), 
                      .Names = c("Nome", "Vendas"), 
                      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

barplot(empresas$Vendas, names.arg = empresas$Nome, main = "Venda por empresa de TI")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você consegue formatar os `labels` do eixo y também caso queira, por exemplo:

```
barplot(empresas$Vendas, names.arg = empresas$Nome, main = "Venda por empresa de TI",
        axes = FALSE)
axis(2, at = c(0, 3e5, 6e5), 
 labels = c("0", "300.000","600.000"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou, outro exemplo:

```
barplot(empresas$Vendas, names.arg = empresas$Nome, main = "Venda por empresa de TI",
        axes = FALSE)
axis(2, at = c(0, 3e5, 6e5), 
     labels = c("0", "300 mil","600 mil"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas eu não consigo arrumar o formato dos números?

Comment: rode `options(scipen=5)` antes de fazer o gráfico, assim não vai ficar com a notação científica

Comment: @Rafael, dá para formatar o eixo y sim, inclusive colocando texto, vou colocar um exemplo de como fazer isso